# Tkinter: Is it possible to make the Tkinter window open where it was closed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Like the title says, is it possible to make a Tk window open where it was closed? similar to how when you close a browser window, if you open a new one it'll open in the last position you closed it. Im restarting my program with this line of code:

```
python = sys.executable
os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

but instead of it resetting the window position I'd like it to stay where it was closed.

I realise I can set the window position to where I'd like it to open through the geometry of the window, but as the program is used on different computers, some which have more monitors than others, its quite a hassle trying to get the screen position correct for them all.

Edit:
I can't seem to get it, this is the code where it closes and restarts my program.

```
def copyandclose():
    all_stuff = listbox.get(0, END)
    all_stuff_list = list(all_stuff)
    for i in all_stuff_list:
        master.clipboard_append(i + '\n')
        file = open('something.txt', 'a')
        file.write(i + '\n')
    file.write('\n' + '-----------' + '\n\n')
    file.close()
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

where inside this would i add the code to update the window geometry, or would it be a lot easier to get the position of the window right after its created, then updating it while it moves. if so how would i do that

This is the start of my program

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys, os

#Main Windows Settings
master = Tk()
master.geometry("700x270+953+525")
master.title(string="My Program")
frame = Frame(master)

#Sets background to grey18
label = Label(master, bg="grey18", width=700, height=270)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Sure. When exiting your program (or even when the window is moved), write the window's position to your config file. Read it out at startup and use it to position the window.

Comment: @kindall Thank you! If it's not too much of hassle, could you please reply the line of code in which I'd use just to specifically do this. Tk window is set as master.

Comment: @Kalib: It's not one line of code, and your example code has no config file. Here's some more information that may help: If `root = tk.Tk()`, then `root.winfo_geometry()` will return a "geometry string" describing the size and on-screen location of root window. Geometry strings are described [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html). Also note that you may have to call `root.update_idletasks()` first if `mainloop()` hasn't been called yet.

Comment: @martineau Oh okay, thank you for the info. Ill have a play around with it and try figure out how to implement it into my program :)

Comment: @martineau  I edited the post a little, could you please check that out and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short example of doing what I was explaining in my comments. The configuration file, if it exists, contains only what's called a Tkinter [*geometry string*](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html), otherwise a default value is used. It assumes the configuration file is in the same directory as the script itself.

Just before the application restarts itself in the `copyandclose()`, function, it updates (or creates) this file by writing the current geometry string into it.

```
import os
import sys
from Tkinter import *

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "my_config.txt"
CONFIG_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), CONFIG_FILE_NAME)
DEFAULT_GEOMETRY = "700x270+953+525"

def copyandclose():
    # Update / create configuration file.
    with open(CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "wt") as file:
        file.write(master.winfo_geometry() + '\n')
    # Restart application.
    os.execl(sys.executable,
             '"%s"' % __file__,
             '"%s"' % os.path.basename(__file__))

# Try to read config file.
try:
    with open(CONFIG_FILE_PATH, "rt") as file:
        line = next(file)  # Read first line.
        geometry = line.rstrip('\n')  # Remove trailing newline.
except IOError:
    geometry = DEFAULT_GEOMETRY


master = Tk()
master.geometry(geometry)
master.title(string="My Program")
frame = Frame(master)

label = Label(master, bg="grey18", width=700, height=270)
label.place(x=0, y=0)

button = Button(master, text="Copy and close", anchor=S, command=copyandclose)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thats perfect, Thank You! I can't upvote is cause of my rep lol. but ty, thats exactly what I want.

Comment: Kalib: Glad to hear it helped and don't worry about not upvoting—I understand about the limitations due to rep. Note you can add other items to the configuration file if you wish. In fact you might also want to look into another file format, using the `json` or even Python's own `pickle` module, both of which would make storing and reading back whole data-structures containing settings values almost trivial. I also suggest you upgrade to Python 3 as soon as you can...no reason learning an obsolete version of the language.

Comment: Yes, will definitely look into those two things. And i will eventually upgrade to python 3, Just thought I'd like to start from where it all began at the early stages of python haha. Then when I do upgrade, I'll be able to better appreciate the smaller things that are improved.